# Change input element with jQuery ID selection and css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background-color

I'm trying to change the background color of an input element from a function using jQuery.css syntax. In a function, called at `ready` event, I execute:

```
$("#inputID_1").css("background-color", "red");
```

But the color does not become red.

I can use:

```
<input type='text' id=' inputID_1 ' style="background-color:blue" />
```

in the html to change the color.  Or:

```
$("input").css("background-color", "gray");
```

in JavaScript. But the ability to use the jQuery-ID selection doesn't seem to work!

You can find a JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mjs1138/fFhCJ/59/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The gaps in your HTML elements ID's do make a difference - remove them out and it will work just as you wish.

So, change:

```
<input type='text' id=' inputID_1 ' style="background-color:blue" />
<input type='text' id=' inputID_2 ' />
```

to

```
<input type='text' id='inputID_1' style="background-color:blue" />
<input type='text' id='inputID_2' />
```

Here's a working [**jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/fFhCJ/62/)

Comment: hmm... I noticed the spaces when building my jsFiddle; seems to me they were being put in by the TidyUp button so I assumed they would be fine.  I also thought I'd tried removing them and still had the problem.  But... this obviously works! So now back to the project code to try again.  Thanks --- Mike

Answer (score 0):

The problem are the spaces after and before your ID value. Remove them and it will work.